# How to take into account measurements of out-of-bound cases in a statistical pair-wise comparison?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-comparisons

If I have time measurements of different methods, but there is a maximum time. 
**What should I do with the cases where the maximum time was reached, but not the goal?** Should I simply ignore them, or is there a way to take them into account?

---

*Background:*

I am doing simulations of different algorithms, and I compare them using the number of steps they need to reach their goal. To prevent the algorithms from running too long I put a maximum of 500 steps. There are some cases in which some algorithms reached the maximum number of steps, but did not arrive to the goal.

I am doing a Wilcoxon signed-rank test (using a Python package: [`scipy.stats.wilcoxon`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html)) to compare the algorithms pair-wise. Is there a way to take these cases - where the goal was not reached within time - into account?

Comment: Since you're using a non-parametric test that is based on ranks, why not just code all the "out of time" cases with 501 (or any other number greater than 500)? You're not assuming the items are continuous, so the fact that the difference between 499 and 500 isn't the same as the difference between 500 and 501 is less of an issue.